# WMTS (USA National Map service) will not export in QGIS layout but other WMS will at same scale

Tags: qgis-3, wms, layouts, wmts

I have a QGIS 3.22.9 (Ubuntu Linux) layout.  On export to PDF (or Tiff) a WMTS layer from the USGS National Map Services website will not show in the final export.  Other vector data on top of the WMTS export fine, as do the map features like scale bars and grids.

Interestingly, a WMS (c.2000 USGS Topo maps) will export  There is no change in scale.  Both data are freely available from the USA [National Map](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/services/).

Below is a screen shot of the export options where 'Layers' is the WMTS.

[Here is the URL](https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) for the WMTS data that will not export.

[Here is the URL](https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/WMSServer) for the WMS data that will export.

The layout is scaled to 1:20000.  The CRS is WGS84/UTM12N or EPSG 32612.

Why will the WMS export fine but not the WMTS?

[image]

Comment: Try using the REST MapServer service instead of the WMTS https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/

Comment: The rest service displays just fine but there is the same problem on export.

Comment: Hmmm, can't reproduce, works for me. Can you include page size and export resolution (DPI) in your Q.?

Comment: check the network with the network logger plugin, you may be getting a timeout on the tiles requests which will be for higher resolution tiles than the screen display

Answer (score 0):

Export DPI was set to 300DPI.  Reducing the DPI fixed the issue.